# variable inside Observable subscription gets empty value

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, rxjs-observables

I know that Observables take some time to get data while javascript keeps running the others codes and that is troubling me a lot.

I have used ngrx in my angular project. Here, I am trying to fetch some data from the store which is working fine. Then, I convert this data stream into `string[]` which is also working fine.
To use this `string[]` me `subscribe`to this observable. And inside subscription I try to assign the value to other values named `filterSizeValues`.

Here, the problem comes. If I `console.log`this `filterSizeValues`initially I got and empty array. When the observable finishes his job `filterSizeValues` variable is filled with data.

But I can not effort `filterSizeValues` variable to be empty array initially. What can I do?

I have already searched the solution in the internet but nothing is working out.

Help me out please. And Many Many Thanks in advance.

Here is my code;

```
this.sizeTargetingStore$.dispatch(SizeTargetingActions.getSizeTargeting({
        campaignId: this.campaignId,
        lineItemId: this.lineItemId
      }));
```

Here I am accessing the store to get data.

```
this.sizeTargeting$
      .pipe(switchMap(sizes=>{
        let temporary:string[] = [];
        sizes.forEach(eachSize=>{
          temporary.push(eachSize.name);
        })
        this.filterSizeValues$ = of(temporary);
        return this.filterSizeValues$;
      }))
      .subscribe(size_name=>{
        this.filters.set('size_name', size_name);
      })
```

Here, I am trying to `set` the filter values.

I also tried this way also.

```
this.sizeTargeting$
      .pipe(switchMap(sizes=>{
        let temporary:string[] = [];
        sizes.forEach(eachSize=>{
          temporary.push(eachSize.name);
        })
        this.filterSizeValues$ = of(temporary);
        return this.filterSizeValues$;
      }))
      .subscribe(size_name=>{
        this.filterSizeValues = size_name
      })
      this.filters.set('size_name', this.filterSizeValues);
```

But all ways filters set to an empty array.
Anyone can help me out please?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understand your request.. do you need the property "filterSizeValues" to be initially evaluated as an empty array?

Comment: Initially "filterSizeValues" is []. After subscribe I want "filterSizeValues" to be filled some strings like ['A','B'] whatever is stored in the state. But it is first showing empty array then data loaded. That's why my html component is not rendering properly.

Comment: So it seems that your code is working as you want but the problem is only in its representation in the view, is that correct? In this case, since the initial value is an empty array an this causes troubles when rendering, could you just use an *ngIf and show some kind of "skeleton" component when the value is empty? Like those you can see in any modern app when the content is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you have 2 possibilities, either filter out the empty values or skip the first value. You can do so with the `filter` and `skip` **rxjs** operator respectively.

Also I believe that you are misusing the `switchMap` operator, since you are not using asynchronous operations within your `switchMap` we can use the `map` operator instead, so below I have a simplified version of your code with your 2 options to fix your problem.

**Option 1:**

```js
this.sizeTargeting$.pipe(
  filter(sizes => sizes.length > 0),         // filter out empty array values
  map(sizes => sizes.map(size => size.name)) // perform your remap
).subscribe(sizes => {
  this.filterSizeValues = size_name;         // Only arrays with values will reach this step
});
```

**Option 2:**

```js
this.sizeTargeting$.pipe(
  skip(1),                                   // skip the first value
  map(sizes => sizes.map(size => size.name)) // perform your remap
).subscribe(sizes => {
  this.filterSizeValues = size_name;         // Only arrays with values will reach this step
});
```

Comment: I try to console below line outside subscribe block.
console.log("Filter size value is", this.filterSizeValues);

It's giving me an empty array which still remains the same problem.

Comment: And what is printed into the console?

Comment: It is printing:       Filter size value is []

Comment: You need to `console.log(...)` (or which ever code you want to run on new values) inside the subscribe block, that is when you get the latest value.

Comment: Is it possible to get "filterSizeValues" value outside subscribe block.

Comment: The short answer is no. The more precise answer is that it depends on **when** you call the code outside the subscribe block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really mean it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I subscribe to something that I am waiting on to return what I do is I set up a Subject:

```
  private componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
```

then in the Observable piping and subscription I do it as:

```
this.sizeTargeting$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
    .subscribe((sizes: YourTypeHere[]) => {
       if(sizes) {
           //Do what I need to do with my sizes here, populate what I need,
           //dispatch any other actions needed.
       }
    })
```